# How can I optimize the memory usage of mysql server on ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql

I have an ubuntu server version 20.04.2 LTS.
On it I have installed just mysql version 8.0.25-0ubuntu0.20.04.1

It's a dedicated server so I have my.cnf set up as this:

```
innodb_dedicated_server = 1
skip_name_resolve       = 1
key_buffer_size         = 16M
myisam-recover-options  = BACKUP
max_binlog_size         = 100M
```

The server is a vmware VM configured with 10GB RAM, 8 CPU (2 core, 4 sockets).

The problem is this; every now and then (once in a day or every 2 days) mysql crashes saying "out of memory". For example, just a moment ago I checked my free memory with free -m and it was 130.
I thought probably is normal because of innodb_dedicated_server. I have run an alter table on a table with 3.5 million rows and that's when it crashed. Probably it did not have enough memory for the alter table?

How can I optimize this? I would like it to use as much memory as possible but I don't want it to crash for an alter table...

Any help?
Thanks!

EDIT - log files:

```
Jul 20 00:08:35 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL snapd[937]: storehelpers.go:551: cannot refresh: snap has no updates available: "core", "core18", "core20", "lxd"
Jul 20 00:08:35 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL snapd[937]: autorefresh.go:513: auto-refresh: all snaps are up-to-date
Jul 20 00:09:01 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL CRON[33080]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/lib/php/sessionclean; fi)
Jul 20 00:17:01 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL CRON[33096]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jul 20 00:39:01 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL CRON[33125]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/lib/php/sessionclean; fi)
Jul 20 01:09:01 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL CRON[33159]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/lib/php/sessionclean; fi)
Jul 20 01:17:01 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL CRON[33175]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jul 20 01:38:46 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL systemd[1]: fwupd.service: Succeeded.
Jul 20 01:39:01 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL CRON[33216]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/lib/php/sessionclean; fi)
Jul 20 02:09:01 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL CRON[33255]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/lib/php/sessionclean; fi)
Jul 20 02:17:02 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL CRON[33269]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jul 20 02:39:01 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL CRON[33293]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/lib/php/sessionclean; fi)
Jul 20 03:09:01 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL CRON[33327]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/lib/php/sessionclean; fi)
Jul 20 03:10:01 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL CRON[33330]: (root) CMD (test -e /run/systemd/system || SERVICE_MODE=1 /sbin/e2scrub_all -A -r)
Jul 20 03:17:01 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL CRON[33341]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jul 20 03:31:24 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL systemd[1]: Starting Ubuntu Advantage APT and MOTD Messages...
Jul 20 03:31:26 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL systemd[1]: ua-messaging.service: Succeeded.
Jul 20 03:31:26 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL systemd[1]: Finished Ubuntu Advantage APT and MOTD Messages.
Jul 20 03:39:01 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL CRON[33388]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/lib/php/sessionclean; fi)
Jul 20 04:09:01 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL CRON[33423]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/lib/php/sessionclean; fi)
Jul 20 04:17:01 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL CRON[33436]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jul 20 04:39:01 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL CRON[33459]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/lib/php/sessionclean; fi)
Jul 20 05:09:01 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL CRON[33496]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/lib/php/sessionclean; fi)
Jul 20 05:17:01 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL CRON[33506]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jul 20 05:39:01 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL CRON[33532]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/lib/php/sessionclean; fi)
Jul 20 06:09:01 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL CRON[33568]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/lib/php/sessionclean; fi)
Jul 20 06:10:24 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL systemd[1]: Starting Daily apt upgrade and clean activities...
Jul 20 06:10:28 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL systemd[1]: apt-daily-upgrade.service: Succeeded.
Jul 20 06:10:28 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL systemd[1]: Finished Daily apt upgrade and clean activities.
Jul 20 06:17:01 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL CRON[33675]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jul 20 06:25:01 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL CRON[33688]: (root) CMD (test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily ))
Jul 20 06:39:01 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL CRON[33782]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/lib/php/sessionclean; fi)
Jul 20 07:09:01 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL CRON[33826]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/lib/php/sessionclean; fi)
Jul 20 07:17:01 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL CRON[33842]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jul 20 07:39:01 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL CRON[33868]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/lib/php/sessionclean; fi)
Jul 20 08:09:02 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL CRON[33940]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/lib/php/sessionclean; fi)
Jul 20 08:17:01 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL CRON[33961]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jul 20 08:39:02 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL CRON[34011]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/lib/php/sessionclean; fi)
Jul 20 09:09:01 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL CRON[34089]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/lib/php/sessionclean; fi)
Jul 20 09:17:01 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL CRON[34132]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jul 20 09:17:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL systemd[1]: Started Session 529 of user lorenzo.
Jul 20 09:39:01 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL CRON[34363]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/lib/php/sessionclean; fi)
Jul 20 09:42:01 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL CRON[34370]: (root) CMD (   test -x /etc/cron.daily/popularity-contest && /etc/cron.daily/popularity-contest --crond)
Jul 20 10:07:00 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL systemd[1]: Starting Message of the Day...
Jul 20 10:07:12 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL 50-motd-news[34482]:  * Super-optimized for small spaces - read how we shrank the memory
Jul 20 10:07:12 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL 50-motd-news[34482]:    footprint of MicroK8s to make it the smallest full K8s around.
Jul 20 10:07:12 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL 50-motd-news[34482]:    https://ubuntu.com/blog/microk8s-memory-optimisation
Jul 20 10:07:12 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL systemd[1]: motd-news.service: Succeeded.
Jul 20 10:07:12 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL systemd[1]: Finished Message of the Day.
Jul 20 10:09:01 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL CRON[34503]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/lib/php/sessionclean; fi)
Jul 20 10:17:03 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL CRON[34525]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jul 20 10:39:02 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL CRON[34591]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/lib/php/sessionclean; fi)
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195446] mysqld invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x100cca(GFP_HIGHUSER_MOVABLE), order=0, oom_score_adj=0
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195450] CPU: 2 PID: 34627 Comm: mysqld Not tainted 5.4.0-77-generic #86-Ubuntu
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195451] Hardware name: VMware, Inc. VMware Virtual Platform/440BX Desktop Reference Platform, BIOS 6.00 12/12/2018
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195452] Call Trace:
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195460]  dump_stack+0x6d/0x8b
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195464]  dump_header+0x4f/0x1eb
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195467]  oom_kill_process.cold+0xb/0x10
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195470]  out_of_memory.part.0+0x1df/0x3d0
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195472]  out_of_memory+0x6d/0xd0
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195475]  __alloc_pages_slowpath+0xd5e/0xe50
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195479]  __alloc_pages_nodemask+0x2d0/0x320
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195481]  alloc_pages_current+0x87/0xe0
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195484]  __page_cache_alloc+0x72/0x90
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195486]  pagecache_get_page+0xbf/0x300
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195489]  filemap_fault+0x6b2/0xa50
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195492]  ? unlock_page_memcg+0x12/0x20
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195494]  ? page_add_file_rmap+0xff/0x1a0
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195497]  ? filemap_map_pages+0x24c/0x380
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195500]  ext4_filemap_fault+0x32/0x50
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195502]  __do_fault+0x3c/0x130
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195505]  do_fault+0x24b/0x640
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195507]  __handle_mm_fault+0x4c5/0x7a0
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195509]  handle_mm_fault+0xca/0x200
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195512]  do_user_addr_fault+0x1f9/0x450
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195515]  __do_page_fault+0x58/0x90
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195517]  do_page_fault+0x2c/0xe0
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195520]  page_fault+0x34/0x40
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195522] RIP: 0033:0x7ffb5f76afff
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195527] Code: Bad RIP value.
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195528] RSP: 002b:00007ffb0c051ea0 EFLAGS: 00010246
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195530] RAX: 00000000000000a0 RBX: 00007ff8ec513020 RCX: 0000000000000000
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195531] RDX: 0000000000000014 RSI: 00007ffb0c051ef0 RDI: 00007ff8ec00e6b0
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195532] RBP: 00007ffb0c051ee0 R08: 00007ff8ec00e6b0 R09: 00007ff8ec00e70c
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195533] R10: 00007ff8ec00e70c R11: 00007ffb0c051e58 R12: 00007ff8ec051e40
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195533] R13: 0000000000000014 R14: 00007ffb0c051ef0 R15: 0000000000000014
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195535] Mem-Info:
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195546] active_anon:2436714 inactive_anon:283 isolated_anon:0
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195546]  active_file:185 inactive_file:37 isolated_file:0
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195546]  unevictable:4634 dirty:3 writeback:0 unstable:0
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195546]  slab_reclaimable:16654 slab_unreclaimable:32409
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195546]  mapped:2438 shmem:696 pagetables:5722 bounce:0
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195546]  free:27493 free_pcp:1798 free_cma:0
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195549] Node 0 active_anon:9746856kB inactive_anon:1132kB active_file:740kB inactive_file:148kB unevictable:18536kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB mapped:9752kB dirty:12kB writeback:0kB shmem:2784kB shmem_thp: 0kB shmem_pmdmapped: 0kB anon_thp: 0kB writeback_tmp:0kB unstable:0kB all_unreclaimable? no
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195550] Node 0 DMA free:15860kB min:104kB low:128kB high:152kB active_anon:0kB inactive_anon:0kB active_file:0kB inactive_file:0kB unevictable:0kB writepending:0kB present:15992kB managed:15908kB mlocked:0kB kernel_stack:0kB pagetables:0kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:0kB local_pcp:0kB free_cma:0kB
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195554] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 2911 9861 9861 9861
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195557] Node 0 DMA32 free:47248kB min:19920kB low:24900kB high:29880kB active_anon:2927744kB inactive_anon:92kB active_file:444kB inactive_file:0kB unevictable:0kB writepending:4kB present:3129216kB managed:3063680kB mlocked:0kB kernel_stack:952kB pagetables:5864kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:3104kB local_pcp:296kB free_cma:0kB
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195560] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 6949 6949 6949
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195562] Node 0 Normal free:46864kB min:47552kB low:59440kB high:71328kB active_anon:6819112kB inactive_anon:1040kB active_file:480kB inactive_file:740kB unevictable:18536kB writepending:8kB present:7340032kB managed:7124380kB mlocked:18536kB kernel_stack:5784kB pagetables:17024kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:4088kB local_pcp:444kB free_cma:0kB
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195566] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0 0
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195568] Node 0 DMA: 1*4kB (U) 0*8kB 1*16kB (U) 1*32kB (U) 1*64kB (U) 1*128kB (U) 1*256kB (U) 0*512kB 1*1024kB (U) 1*2048kB (M) 3*4096kB (M) = 15860kB
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195575] Node 0 DMA32: 932*4kB (UE) 697*8kB (UE) 593*16kB (UE) 198*32kB (ME) 210*64kB (UME) 63*128kB (UME) 1*256kB (M) 0*512kB 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 46888kB
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195583] Node 0 Normal: 1338*4kB (UME) 656*8kB (UE) 246*16kB (UE) 128*32kB (UME) 131*64kB (UME) 93*128kB (UME) 14*256kB (UE) 2*512kB (ME) 1*1024kB (M) 1*2048kB (M) 0*4096kB = 46600kB
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195592] Node 0 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=1048576kB
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195593] Node 0 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=2048kB
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195594] 3206 total pagecache pages
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195595] 0 pages in swap cache
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195596] Swap cache stats: add 0, delete 0, find 0/0
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195596] Free swap  = 0kB
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195597] Total swap = 0kB
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195598] 2621310 pages RAM
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195599] 0 pages HighMem/MovableOnly
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195599] 70318 pages reserved
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195600] 0 pages cma reserved
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195600] 0 pages hwpoisoned
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195601] Tasks state (memory values in pages):
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195602] [  pid  ]   uid  tgid total_vm      rss pgtables_bytes swapents oom_score_adj name
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195610] [    567]     0   567    16228      966   139264        0          -250 systemd-journal
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195618] [    598]     0   598     5551     1083    73728        0         -1000 systemd-udevd
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195620] [    612]   101   612     4602      820    81920        0             0 systemd-network
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195623] [    827]     0   827    70052     4498    94208        0         -1000 multipathd
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195625] [    878]   102   878     5972     1328    86016        0             0 systemd-resolve
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195627] [    879]   100   879    22557      976    77824        0             0 systemd-timesyn
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195629] [    891]     0   891    11885      823    77824        0             0 VGAuthService
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195630] [    892]     0   892    40670      402    77824        0             0 vmtoolsd
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195632] [    920]     0   920    59126      490    98304        0             0 accounts-daemon
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195634] [    923]     0   923     1703      577    45056        0             0 cron
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195635] [    924]   105   924     1913      817    61440        0          -900 dbus-daemon
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195637] [    929]     0   929    20492      498    61440        0             0 irqbalance
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195639] [    931]     0   931     7269     2723    90112        0             0 networkd-dispat
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195640] [    932]     0   932     8544     1105   106496        0             0 nmbd
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195643] [    935]   103   935    56125      526    81920        0             0 rsyslogd
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195645] [    937]     0   937   455043     3781   360448        0          -900 snapd
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195647] [    947]     0   947     4207      444    69632        0             0 systemd-logind
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195648] [    951]     0   951      948      500    45056        0             0 atd
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195650] [    964]     0   964     1497      626    49152        0             0 login
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195652] [    984]     0   984     3044      889    69632        0         -1000 sshd
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195654] [    996]     0   996    26978     2694   110592        0             0 unattended-upgr
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195656] [   1013]     0  1013    58179      213    86016        0             0 polkitd
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195658] [   1048]     0  1048    12242     1806   135168        0             0 smbd
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195665] [   1063]     0  1063    11686      859   131072        0             0 smbd-notifyd
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195666] [   1064]     0  1064    11688      797   131072        0             0 cleanupd
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195668] [   1090]     0  1090    12238     1058   131072        0             0 lpqd
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195670] [   1355]  1000  1355     4626      653    81920        0             0 systemd
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195676] [   1356]  1000  1356    42217      865    94208        0             0 (sd-pam)
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195682] [   1361]  1000  1361     2104      926    57344        0             0 bash
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195684] [   4014]     0  4014    60297      718   102400        0             0 upowerd
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195686] [  20666]   110 20666  4128901  2416524 20922368        0             0 mysqld
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195688] [  29379]     0 29379    12332     1183   135168        0             0 smbd
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195690] [  34134]     0 34134     3482      849    65536        0             0 sshd
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195692] [  34276]  1000 34276     3515      539    69632        0             0 sshd
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195694] [  34277]  1000 34277     2102      935    57344        0             0 bash
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195696] [  34286]     0 34286     2396      706    57344        0             0 sudo
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195698] [  34289]     0 34289     2096      657    53248        0             0 su
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195699] [  34290]     0 34290     1809      460    49152        0             0 bash
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195701] oom-kill:constraint=CONSTRAINT_NONE,nodemask=(null),cpuset=/,mems_allowed=0,global_oom,task_memcg=/system.slice/mysql.service,task=mysqld,pid=20666,uid=110
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195886] Out of memory: Killed process 20666 (mysqld) total-vm:16515604kB, anon-rss:9666096kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB, UID:110 pgtables:20432kB oom_score_adj:0
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.658941] oom_reaper: reaped process 20666 (mysqld), now anon-rss:0kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 8.
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
Jul 20 10:41:02 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL systemd[1]: Started MySQL Community Server.
```

Comment: If your database is so large that it needs more memory, add more memory.

Comment: I could add more memory but I don't think the problem is "more memory". If I set bufferpoolsize = 2G probably do not crash anymore. As I have set innodb_dedicated_server it should be automatic, why is it crashing?

Comment: What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  What other apps are running in the VM?  What operation was being performed when it crashed?

Comment: 'innodb_buffer_pool_size', '8589934592'. As written in the description it's a dedicated server, in that moment I was doing an alter table

Comment: Please post last 400 lines of your error log for analysis.

Comment: I have added the log files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to reconsider this situation reported in your error log -

```
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195596] Free swap  = 0kB
Jul 20 10:40:55 ITMI-PHSE-MYSQL kernel: [597449.195597] Total swap = 0kB
```

I would recommend 6 GB minimum swap for your OS to avoid OOM.

Better to be slow for some milliseconds or seconds than OOM stopped.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I am not sure regarding how to set 6GB minimum swap, I will investigate and apply it. However I do not understand why is it happening. it's a dedicated machine with just innodb_dedicated_server=1

Comment: Even a dedicated server can reach Out Of Memory.  Consider our Free My Top 4 Global Variable Suggestions.

Comment: From any browser search request - ubuntu swap space tutorial - for information to assist with creating swap space.